# Can't get imagemagick to work on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, imagemagick

I'm trying to install `ImageMagick-6.5.9-10-Q16-windows-dll.exe` on `windows server 2008 x86`, the installation went good but in my application I can get it to work.

I'm doing exactly the same steps on my local `windows 7` machine and it's works fine there.

I'm going now to do the last try and restart the live server(!), but at this point there any thing that I didn't test except this step.

Is there any know problems, are know steps that I need to take in this case?

The error that I get is indicating that I can't load the dll's:

> ```
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
> ```

Comment: How are you interfacing with Image Magick? Via the COM object? Or the `convert` command line? There should be absolutally no need to restart the live server, as I've installed this on half a dozen 2k8 and 2k8r2 servers without any need for restarts

Comment: I'm using it with a `.net` wrapper, called `imagemagick.net`. after restarting, it start working as expected. this is not understood  to me at all.

Comment: Does imagemagick.net use %PATH% to locate IM or does it target it directly?